# Writing a Java program using sockets to connect to a PLC (Programmable Logic Controller)

Tags: java, sockets, plc

I am writing a program that grabs analog and discrete data points from a PLC (Allen Bradley 1756 L63) via Sockets.  So far I am having trouble just creating a socket.  My code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class PLCServer
{
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException
    {
        // IP address of the ethernet card
        String ENBTIP = "192.168.10.14";
        DataInputStream socketReader = null;
        PrintStream socketWriter = null;

        try 
        {
                Socket client = new Socket(ENBTIP, 9100);
                socketReader = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                socketWriter = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.out.println("Error setting up socket connection");
                System.out.println("host: 192.168.10.14 port: 9100");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error setting up socket connection: " + e);
                System.out.println("host: 192.168.10.14 port: 9100");
            }
        // Debugging code
        // System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName(ENBTIP).isReachable(10000));
    }
}
```

When I run the program I get a connection refused exception.

Output:

```
nick@ubuntu:~/Java Programs/PLC Program$ java PLCServer 
Error setting up socket connection: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
host: 192.168.10.14 port: 9100
```

Can anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: `Connection refused` <-- are you sure about the host and port? This means either there is nothing listening on that port (or that there is a firewall preventing access, which I doubt). Also, are you sure it is TCP and not UDP?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code; whatever it is that is supposed to be listenen on that IP:port isn't, or isn't accepting connections from the machine you're running this code on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try 'ping 192.168.10.14' first, if it has response (and it should be), then try 'telnet 192.168.10.14 9100'. If it has some response like:
Trying 192.168.10.14...
Connected to 192.168.10.14.
Then your java code is somehow wrong. Otherwise it will be the network problem.

Comment: I found a reference that had all the TCP ports that Allen Bradley cards use and of course, I was using the wrong port. Telnet to that IP with port 44818 worked and my Java program also worked.  Thanks!